# How to efficiently select elements from a Hash?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, associations

How can I write an efficient version of the following selection statement:

```
Keys[Select[hash, # < constant &]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

hash can be made from:

```
hash = Association[Table[i -> i^2, {i, 1, 10^6}]];
```

On my computer, a last year MacBook Pro, it takes almost a half second. However, this is non an acceptable time for working with Hashs. Any other ways to do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: I will remark that the analogous operation, on `Range[10^6]^2` (that is, a `List` rather than `Association`), is less than a factor of two faster. So it is not clear that the original expectation of greater speed is reasonable, unless there is a similar claim about speed of `Select` on the raw list.

Comment: @Daniel `Select` *is* pretty slow on raw lists compared to numeric equivalents, when the latter are possible.  Perhaps `Select` could be made to auto-compile like `Fold` etc.?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it is possible to do much to improve this for an `Association` object.  If the conversion to a list of keys and values can be externalized this numeric selection can be performed quite quickly by using [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitStep.html), and [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html) Properties:

```
(* hash randomized to demonstrate order independence *)
hash = Association[RandomSample @ Table[i -> i^2, {i, 1, 10^6}]];

keys   = Keys[hash];
values = Values[hash];

constant = 27;

keys[[
 SparseArray[UnitStep[values - constant], Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]
]]
```

> ```
> {3, 5, 1, 2, 4}
> ```

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

keys[[
 SparseArray[UnitStep[values - constant], Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]
]] // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 0.00680001
> ```

Unfortunately the conversion to lists is two orders of magnitude slower:

```
AccurateTiming[
 Keys[hash];
 Values[hash];
]
```

> ```
> 0.665001
> ```

For the time being you may be better served by a different data structure.